# How to add an editor(MPart) to a Wizard/WizardPage?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

how can I add an Editor to a Wizard or a Wizard Page (e4)? And how can I get an EServicePart from a Wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. Wizards don't support the e4 part mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. Can I only show an existing Editor inside a WizardPage?

Comment: Well what do you mean by 'existing editor'? If you have an editor class of your own you may be able to include it on a wizard page. Most existing editors are 3.x compatibility mode which you can't use at all in a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: Yes I have my own editor class, but i am not able to add this editor inside a scrolled composite in my wizard, because a wizard does not have an own EPartService.